# A more rigorous proof that if $\forall n, \int_{[0,1]} f^n = C$, $f(x) = \chi_{\{f = 1\}}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following problem:

> Let $f \geq 0$ be measurable on $[0,1]$. If there is a constant $C$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\int_{[0,1]} f^n = C$, then show $f(x) = \chi_{\{ f = 1 \}}(x)$ for almost every $x$, i.e. a.e. the characteristic function of the set $\{ x : f(x) = 1 \}$.

Now this much is clear: if $m(\{ f > 1 \}) > 0$, then $\int_{\{ f > 1 \}} f^n \to \infty$. Similarly, $\int_{\{ f < 1 \}} f^n \to 0$. Now I want to conclude that $\int_{\{f = 1\}} f^n = \int_{[0,1]} \chi_{\{f=1\}} = C$.

Essentially, I need to show that $m(\{ f > 1 \}) = m(\{ f < 1 \}) = 0$, but I'm not sure how to do so rigorously.

Comment: once you know $0 \le f \le 1$ use that $f^n \rightarrow I_{f = 1} \le f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D_A=f^{-1} A$.

Then $C=\int f^n = \int_{D_{(0,1)}} f^n +  \int_{D_{ \{ 1 \}}} f^n + \int_{D_{(1,\infty)}} f^n = \int_{D_{(0,1)}} f^n +  m D_{ \{ 1 \}} + \int_{D_{(1,\infty)}} f^n$.

As you noted above, if $m D_{(1,\infty)} >0$, then $\int_{D_{(1,\infty)}} f^n \to \infty$, hence we have $m D_{(1,\infty)} =0$. Since $f(x)^n \downarrow 0$ on $D_{(0,1)}$, we have $\int_{D_{(0,1)}} f^n \to 0$ (DCT). Hence $C=m D_{ \{ 1 \}}$, and so we see that $\int_{D_{(0,1)}} f = 0$ (that is, $n=1$), from which we conclude that $m D_{(0,1)} = 0$.

It follows that $m f^{-1} \{ 0,1\} = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, good catch, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly :-).